# Google Custom Search not returning results in iOS Chrome

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome

I'm adding a Custom Google Search on a mobile page using the following code:

```
<script>
    (function() {
        var cx = 'xxxxxx';
        var gcse = document.createElement('script');
        gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
        gcse.async = true;
        gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') + '//cse.google.com/cse.js?mob=1&cx=' + cx;
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
    })();
</script>
<gcse:search></gcse:search>
```

The search function works for all mobile browsers except on iOS Chrome. On iOS Chrome, the rendered result page is blank with the search bar at the top. I've been using Chrome console to emulate iOS Chrome by specifying the device and the UA to `Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 5_1_1 like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/534.46.0 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/19.0.1084.60 Mobile/9B206 Safari/7534.48.3`. The search results render in Chrome console but it fails when I test it out on the actual mobile device. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Does it work in Safari on your device?  Chrome on iOS uses WebKit/WebView

Comment: @Kinlan yes it works on Safari on my device. I've asked colleagues with older iPhones to test it out as well. It works on Safari, but not iOS Chrome.